# Use sed and grep to extract data for particular months in a file with timestamps

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, sed

I have text file with six years (2011-2016) of data. I want to extract only April and May data of all six years.

```
@STATION_ID,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,TIME(GMT),DATE(GMT),AIR_TEMP(‌​°C) 
IMDE1611_14164B(PITAMPURA),28.7,77.15,0,08/09/2011,33.5 
IMDE1611_14164B(PITAMPURA),28.7,77.15,1,08/09/2011,33.3 
IMDE1611_14164B(PITAMPURA),28.7,77.15,2,08/09/2011,33.8 
IMDE1611_14164B(PITAMPURA),28.7,77.15,3,08/09/2011,33.8 
IMDE1611_14164B(PITAMPURA),28.7,77.15,4,08/09/2011,34.5 
IMDE1611_14164B(PITAMPURA),28.7,77.15,5,08/09/2011,35.0 
IMDE1611_14164B(PITAMPURA),28.7,77.15,6,08/09/2011,34.9 
IMDE1611_14164B(PITAMPURA),28.7,77.15,7,08/09/2011,35.4
```

I am using `grep` and `sed` commands to filter the data but it is not showing the result I want. 
I am using these commands:

```
grep "??-0[4-5]-????" filename.txt > filename.csv
sed -n '/2016-04-01/,/2016-04-30/{/2016-04-30/d; p}' my_delhi.txt
sed -n '/2016-04-01/,/2016-04-30/p' my_delhi.txt
```

Comment: please show a sample of the file. You are trying to use wildcards in grep, but you need to use regex...

Comment: I don't know how to use regrex to getting desired result. Date format is mm:dd:yyyy.

Answer (score 3):

In your file it looks like the date format is actually `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`, but in your commands you assume it is `dd-mm-yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd`.

You should be able to `grep` the April and May lines, assuming the format is `mm/dd/yyyy` with this expression

```
grep -E '(04|05)/[0-9]+/[0-9]+' file
```

if it is `dd/mm/yyyy` then you could use:

```
grep -E '[0-9]+/(04|05)/[0-9]+' file
```

Based on your file sample, these should be specific enough.

#### Notes

- `-E` use extended regex
- `(04|05)` match `04` or `05`
- `[0-9]+` at least one digit (of course we could be more strict here about the exact date formatting, for example a day could be `[0-3][0-9]` and a year `20[0-1][0-9]`, but there does not seem to be a need in this case)

Comment: @Zanna when you use `grep` you make me use `sed` :))

Comment: @Ravexina as long as neither of you uses Perl or Python, it's fine in my book ^_0 lel

Answer (score 3):

You can use something else instead of `/` as `sed`'s delimiter.

```
sed -n '\:08/09/2011:p' file
```

or with regex and '#' as delimiter:

```
sed -nr "\#,[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4},#p" file
```

for April and May only (dd/mm/yyyy):

```
sed -nr "\#,[0-9]{2}/0[45]{1}/[0-9]{4},#p" file
```

or (mm/dd/yyy):

```
sed -nr "\#,0[45]{1}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4},#p" file
```

Comment: Congrats on 10k!

Answer (score 1):

#### Perl approach

```
$ perl -F'/,/' -ane 'print if $F[4]=~/^(04|05)/' input.txt                                                               
IMDE1611_14164B(PITAMPURA),28.7,77.15,2,04/09/2011,33.8 
IMDE1611_14164B(PITAMPURA),28.7,77.15,3,05/09/2011,33.8
```

What happens here is that we use comma as separator for columns, and print if and only if the 4th column (which is date) starts with 04 or 05. This is consistent with [OP's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921705/use-sed-and-grep-to-extract-data-for-particular-months-in-a-file-with-timestamps/921823#comment1455709_921705) where they stated:

> ...Date format is mm:dd:yyyy.